# Counting posts from a category that has sub categories

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a WordPress problem. I have a category C. And this has subcategories A,B,X,Z.

I want to display how many posts are in the subcategories of C in total. I know that there are 204. But I only ever get 184 displayed.

Why is that? Because subcategories A and B are not counted. Why is that? Nobody knows.

Because they start with a letter that comes before C in the alphabet?
I've been looking for the error in the code for so long now, but can't find anything that helps. Now I have also made A times TestA and from B a TestB. And then it counts correctly.

How can I solve this without renaming the subcategories?

This is my current code (which is counting exactly what it should if I rename the sub cats).

```
                                $category_args = [
                                    'orderby'     => 'name',
                                    'order'       => 'ASC',
                                    'hide_empty'  => 0,
                                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                                    'taxonomy'    => 'category',
                                    'pad_counts'  => true, // Count Sub Cats posts to Cats
                                    'exclude'     => [1, 69, 71], // Exclude categories: "Uncategorized", "Authors", and "Editorial Office"
                                ];
                                
                                $categories = get_categories($category_args);
                                $categories = array_filter($categories, fn($category) => $category->parent === 0); // Don't show subcategories
                                
                                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                                    $child_categories = get_categories(['child_of' => $category->term_id, 'hide_empty' => 0]);
                                    $post_count = 0;
                                
                                    if (!empty($child_categories)) {
                                        foreach ($child_categories as $child_category) {
                                            $post_count += $child_category->count;
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        $post_count = $category->count;
                                    }
                                
                                    if ($post_count > 0) {
                                        echo '<li class="styleCheckbox">';
                                        echo '<input type="checkbox" data-select="sectionFilter" id="section_' . $category->term_id . '" value="' . $category->term_id . '">';
                                        echo '<label for="section_' . $category->term_id . '">';
                                        echo '<span class="connector">';
                                        echo '<span class="filter-name">' . $category->name . '</span>';
                                        echo '<span class="filter-counter">' . $post_count . '</span>';
                                        echo '</span>';
                                        echo '</label>';
                                        echo '</li>';
                                    }
                                }
```

Is it a bug or am I stupid?

### Clarification

It's not about counting posts, it's about child categories that are NOT being counted while others in the same hierarchy are counted without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your category structure includes all posts within subcategories of category C:

```bash
          Category C
        --------------
       /    |     |   \
      A     B     X    Z
     / \   / \   / \  / \
   ... ... ...
```

But, when counting posts in subcategories, specifically when their names precede the parent category's name alphabetically, you get an incorrect post count.

The issue might be in the way WordPress handles the `pad_counts` parameter or how categories are being filtered out. The `pad_counts` parameter should indeed count posts in subcategories but might be getting affected by the way categories are being filtered or by some other unforeseen issue in WordPress's internal handling of categories.

You could try and target category C and its subcategories directly without relying on `pad_counts` or filtering categories post-fetch, using [`get_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/):

```php
$category_id = {ID_OF_CATEGORY_C}; // Replace with the actual ID of Category C
$subcategory_args = [
    'child_of'     => $category_id,
    'hide_empty'   => 0,
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'taxonomy'     => 'category'
];

// Fetch all subcategories of Category C
$subcategories = get_categories($subcategory_args);

$total_post_count = 0;
// Iterate through each subcategory to sum up the post counts
foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
    $total_post_count += $subcategory->count;
}

// $total_post_count should contain the total number of posts in Category C and its subcategories.
echo "Total posts in Category C and its subcategories: " . $total_post_count;
```

---

> I need to have a function that gets the number of posts in ALL categories, not only the "buggy one". How do I adjust your code? I was able to combine the two codes.
>
> Anyway, your code results in a count of 184 posts. As before. No difference :-(

One potential cause for consistently getting an incorrect count could be related to how WordPress categorizes and counts posts, including potential issues with post visibility (such as drafts or private posts being counted unexpectedly) or categories being excluded unintentionally.

Given the limitations observed with `get_categories()` and the `pad_counts` parameter, you might consider a custom database query may be necessary to make sure accuracy. That can bypass potential issues with the WordPress functions and give you direct control over the count.
You can then count only published posts, to avoid discrepancies with draft or private posts.

For instance:

```php
function get_all_category_post_counts() {
    global $wpdb;
    // Query to count all published posts in each category, including subcategories
    $query = "
        SELECT p2.term_taxonomy_id, COUNT(*) as post_count
        FROM $wpdb->term_relationships AS p2
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON p2.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts AS p ON p2.object_id = p.ID
        WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'category'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        GROUP BY p2.term_taxonomy_id
    ";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT_K);
    
    // Array to hold category ID => post count
    $category_post_counts = [];
    foreach ($results as $term_taxonomy_id => $result) {
        $term_id = get_term_by('term_taxonomy_id', $term_taxonomy_id, 'category')->term_id;
        $category_post_counts[$term_id] = (int) $result->post_count;
    }
    
    return $category_post_counts;
}

// Usage
$category_post_counts = get_all_category_post_counts();
foreach ($category_post_counts as $category_id => $count) {
    echo "Category ID $category_id has $count posts.<br/>";
}
```

The function [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) is used to convert term taxonomy IDs back to category IDs for clarity, but this step could be optimized or adjusted based on your specific requirements.

---

From [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257235/discussion-between-vonc-and-jonsnow):

```php
function get_all_category_post_counts() {
    $category_args = [
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => false, // Include categories even if they are empty.
        'taxonomy'   => 'category'
    ];

    $categories = get_categories($category_args);
    $category_post_counts = [];

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        // Initialize post count
        $post_count = 0;

        // Get posts in the current category and its subcategories
        $posts_in_category = get_posts([
            'category'    => $category->term_id,
            'numberposts' => -1, // Get all posts
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        ]);

        // Count the posts
        $post_count = count($posts_in_category);

        // Assign the count to the category
        $category_post_counts[$category->term_id] = [
            'name' => $category->name,
            'count' => $post_count
        ];
    }

    return $category_post_counts;
}

// Usage
$category_post_counts = get_all_category_post_counts();
foreach ($category_post_counts as $id => $category_data) {
    echo '<li class="styleCheckbox">';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" data-select="sectionFilter" id="section_' . $id . '" value="' . $id . '">';
    echo '<label for="section_' . $id . '">';
    echo '<span class="connector">';
    echo '<span class="filter-name">' . $category_data['name'] . '</span>';
    echo '<span class="filter-counter">' . $category_data['count'] . '</span>';
    echo '</span>';
    echo '</label>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Hi VonC
Thank you for your idea. 
I need to have a function that gets the amount of posts in ALL categories, not only the "buggy one". How do I adjust your code?

Comment: I was able to combine the two codes.
 Anyway, your code results in a count of 184 posts. As before. No difference :-(

Comment: Ahhhh, with this approach I see the correct amount of posts for the first time! "Category ID 70 has 204 posts."  Yeah! But... isn't it of a risk to use the code like this on a public site? Why was the initial approach not working, what's the difference here?

Comment: I was able to ask CoPilot for a comparison between my old code and yours. He explained the differences and re-wrote your code by using WP's built-in functions. And it works like a charm!!
So, your code did the trick and opened the door, saved my weekend... whatever :-D
Thank you very much for your help, I would not have been able to solve it alone (or with CP alone... ;-))

Comment: @JonSnow Great, well done! Don't forget to post here as an answer your code.

Comment: @JonSnow (I meant to post your own version of your code)

Comment: Will do, as soon as I've fixed the latest issues

Comment: it's crazy: as long as I am only displaying the count, it's all fine. When I start adding cat name and id to the output, the code somehow changes and the result is wrong again :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257235/discussion-between-vonc-and-jonsnow).